# Invalid regular expression flag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a link like the below in my rails application

```
          <%= link_to "Link ", "#", :onclick => "#{abc_path(:type => type)}" %>
```

which throws an error invalid regular expression flag l

how to resolve this ...

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` attribute in HTML needs to contain valid Javascript code.

What you have there is likely to produce something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="/abc/foo?type=mytype">Link</a>
```

which will cause you problems because the browser can't run that as Javascript. If you let us know what you're trying to achieve then we can help you work out the right way to do it.

Comment: I am having a javascript on click on the link which has the link hardcoded like var url = "/abc/foo?type=mtype"; I am removing all hard codings with rails way of using namedroutes